# Show/hide threaded comments pane

Tags: excel, vba

During an import routine I am adding comments to faulty cells (e.g. `rg.AddCommentThreaded "wrong data type"`)

In case there were errors (and therefore new comments) I would like to force the comments pane to be visible (via code). But I can't find a method/property what ever.

I looked into the `application`, `workbook` and `windows`-object ... nothing ...

Am I missing sth - or is there no way to show them via VBA?

[image]

The screenshot shows the button (in German) I want to activate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a button on the Review-tab that shows/hides the new comment pane.

Found the according idMso here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers/blob/master/Office%20365/Semi-Annual/excelcontrols.xlsx. It is within the "GroupThreadedComments"

```vb
Sub showCommentsPane()
With Application.CommandBars
    If .GetPressedMso("ShowThreadedComments") = False Then
        .ExecuteMso "ShowThreadedComments"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```